# Nodemon error while running a ReadMe generator

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, nodemon

Working on an assignment to write a ReadMe Generator,

but when I put in npm start I get the following error:

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and 'C:\Users\Franco\Desktop\Readme-Generator\package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.

```
This isn't code but Stack overflow is dumb sometimes 

at file:///C:/Users/Franco/Desktop/Readme-Generator/index.js:1:18
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:198:25)
at async Promise.all (index 0)
at async ESMLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:385:24)
at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:88:5)
at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:61:12)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Here is my actual code for context
```

```
    const inquirer = require('inquirer')
    
    const questions = [
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'title',
            message: 'What is your project called?',
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'description',
            message: 'Please descbribe your project',
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'installation',
            message: 'Describe how you install the project here',
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'usage',
            message: 'how is your project used?',
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'contribution',
            message: 'who contributed?',
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'test',
            message: 'any tests?',
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'email',
            message: 'What is your email address?',
        },
        {
            type: 'input',
            name: 'github',
            message: 'enter your github username',
        },
        {
            type: 'list',
            name: 'License',
            message: 'Choose your License',
            choices: ['MIT', 'ISC', 'GNUPlv3'],
            filter(val) {
                return val.toLowerCase();
            }
        }
    ]
    
    function runQuery() {
        return inquirer.prompt(questions)
        .then((answers) => {
            console.log(answers)
            return answers
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error)
        })
    }
    
    runQuery
```

Does anyone have any idea what it could be?

Comment: The error is literally telling you what's wrong, except for the very last "To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension." bit which is just silly? You've told Node that you're using modern ESM in your `package.json` file (look at the `type` property). ESM does not have `require`. It has `import`, so either that (which has its own syntax, it's not a function) or update your package file.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans sorry for the silly question, but how or where could I update my package file?

Comment: The `package.json` file for your project is in the root directory of your project.